# Can I pass an argument to ws on message?

Tags: javascript, indexing, websocket, arrow-functions

I'd like, when `WebSocket` "on message" is called, to retrieve the index of my websocket, where data is stacked elsewhere:

```
let indexWS = 0;
for (const item of items) {
    // create ws stream
    const ws = new WebSocket("wss://my-link");

    ws.on('message', async (response) => {
        let data = myData[indexWS]; <<-----
    });
    
    indexWS++;
};
```

i.e. access to `indexWS` index used when I create that websocket.

Can I pass so an argument to `ws.on('message', async (response)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remember the value of `indexWS` that's associated with that instance of the `ws` by defining a variable within the `for` body. That scopes it to just that iteration of the loop (creating a different variable for each iteration), which the handler closes over:

```
let indexWS = 0;
for (const item of items) {
    // create ws stream
    const thisIndex = indexWS;
    const ws = new WebSocket("wss://my-link");

    ws.on('message', async (response) => {
        let data = myData[thisIndex]; // <<-----
    });
    
    indexWS++;
}
```

Here's an example using a timer instead of a websocket:

```js
let indexWS = 0;
console.log("Starting loop");
for (const item of /*items*/["a", "b", "c"]) {
    // create ws stream
    const thisIndex = indexWS;
    // const ws = new WebSocket("wss://my-link");

    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`item = ${item}, thisIndex = ${thisIndex}`);
    }, 800 * indexWS);
    
    indexWS++;
}
console.log("Loop complete");
```

**If** `myData` is unchanging, you could just remember the data itself rather than its index:

```
let indexWS = 0;
for (const item of items) {
    // create ws stream
    const data = myData[indexWS];
    const ws = new WebSocket("wss://my-link");

    ws.on('message', async (response) => {
        // ...use `data` here...
    });
    
    indexWS++;
}
```

But that would be incorrect if the data in `myData` can change between when this loop runs and when the callback occurs, so you'd only want to do it that way with static data.

Here's an example (again with a timer):

```js
let indexWS = 0;
const myData = ["data for a", "data for b", "data for c"];
console.log("Starting loop");
for (const item of /*items*/["a", "b", "c"]) {
    // create ws stream
    const data = myData[indexWS];
    // const ws = new WebSocket("wss://my-link");

    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`item = ${item}, data = ${data}`);
    }, 800 * indexWS);
    
    indexWS++;
}
console.log("Loop complete");
```

Comment: @markzzz - It's an odd one, especially voting then removing the vote (twice; could be different people). Perhaps someone not understanding how `let` and `const` work in loops because they're different from `var`.